# Translating character from a list to my file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, tr

I have lots of files that look like this:

```
136
155
223
783
344
455
230
.
.
.
```

And another file like this (the dictionary):

```
rs6427315   230
rs1171564   455
rs1609666   344
rs728917    155
rs728918    223
rs11264495  783
rs11805559  136
.           .
.           .
.           .
```

And I want a new file that looks like this, that is reading the characters from my first file and substituting them with the match in column 1 from the other file:

```
rs11805559
rs728917
rs728918
rs11264495
rs1609666
rs1609666
rs1171564
rs6427315
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} $1=a[$1]' file2 file1
rs11805559
rs728917
rs728918
rs11264495
rs1609666
rs1171564
rs6427315
```

#### Explanation

Firstly it loops through the second file and stores the array `a[number]=rxxxx`. Then it loops through the first file and replaces the field with its value in the array.

Comment: This can even be shorten some by changing `{$1=a[$1]}1` to `$1=a[$1]`

Comment: That's pretty true, @Jotne, and more clear also. Just updated, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: Create a script-file and use it. (This -- saving a script file -- is good for if you have many input.txt)

```
sed -r 's|^(.*)\t(.*)|s/\2/\1/|' dictionary.txt > dictionary.sed
sed -f dictionary.sed input.txt
```

or if you don't need the script-file

```
sed -r 's|^(.*)\t(.*)|s/\2/\1/|' dictionary.txt | sed -f - input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for number in $(cat file1)
do
  grep " $number$" file2 | { read a b; echo "$a"; }
done
```

I'm not sure you meant that you have files with the *names* `136`, `155`, etc. or if you have a file with the contents which looks like what you've posted above.  I assumed now the latter because your post suggested later that it is just one file.  Feel free to correct my assumption, then I will adjust my answer.