# How to know if my file was translated correctly

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I used this command to loop through file 2, storing an array, then 
go to file 1 and replace the field with its value in the array.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} $1=a[$1]' file2 file1 > new_file
```

For more information on how the file looked you can go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912184/translating-character-from-a-list-to-my-file) (previous post on SO).

My question know is, if there's a way to know if the translation was accomplished correctly for every field. I have a lot of files and I am not 100% sure if my dictionary (file 2) had all the information.

I know that if the value in the file2 wasn't found I will get a blank field in my new file. Is there a way to change this (adding a blank) and add something else, like a word, so I can the grep this word trough all my files and see if it was done correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your awk like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1; next} ($1 in a){$1=a[$1];print;next} {print "NOT FOUND"}' file2 file1
```

Then you will get `NOT FOUND` in output for record in file1 which wasn't found in file2.

Comment: Maybe also leave the original key so you can see which key was NOT FOUND.